# Font resizing commands in a titlepage environment affect later footnotes

Tags: fonts, titles, amsart

Consider the following simple document:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
% geometry makes it easier to see what is happening
\usepackage[paperheight=30mm, paperwidth=60mm]{geometry}
\parindent0pt
\begin{document}

    \begin{titlepage}
        \Huge\bfseries \LaTeX\ title
    \end{titlepage}

    A\footnote{footnote} sentence.

\end{document}
```

At least for me, the output is quite unexpected:

[image]

Notice that the footnote number `1` is typeset using a Huge font. Putting the font resizing command inside a group, as `{\Huge\bfseries \LaTeX\ title}`, does not help as the footnote symbol remains Huge. (The Huge footnote symbols still appear if you remove the `geometry` package.)

If I change to using the `article` document class then I get the more expected output:

[image]

Quite bizarrely, if I keep using `amsart` and remove the  `\LaTeX` command, but keep the space command`\` , then this becomes the more reasonable:

[image]

I have looked through the code and I can't work what is going on here. Can anyone tell me why the footnote symbols Huge when using `amsart`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting puzzle.

It happens that `\footnote` uses `\@makefnmark` that's defined by `amsart.cls` as

```
\def\@makefnmark{%
  \leavevmode
  \raise.9ex\hbox{\fontsize\sf@size\z@\normalfont\@thefnmark}%
}
```

In your case, `\check@mathfonts` had only been done for `\Huge`, so `\sf@size` is the subscript size corresponding to it. This can be solved by issuing `\check@mathfonts` at begin document.

```
\documentclass{amsart}
% geometry makes it easier to see what is happening
\usepackage[paperheight=30mm, paperwidth=60mm]{geometry}

\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{\check@mathfonts}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}
\Huge\bfseries \LaTeX\ title
\end{titlepage}

A\footnote{footnote} sentence.

\end{document}
```

[image]